# jQuery - Change icon on thead tr when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I'm sure this is easy but just cant get my head around the code at the minute.

I have a simple `table` and the `thead` is as follows

```
<thead>
    <tr class="header">
        <th colspan="7">HEADER <span>-</span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

When I click on the `th` within the `thead` I am toggling the `tbody` as follows:

```
$('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').toggle();
});
```

How can I include in the header an icon that changes when the `tbody` is toggled. i.e. when the `table` loads by default the `tbody` shows already and currently shows a minus sign. When clicked how can i change this to a plus sign?

Comment: you can either switch background of the tr or td, or add image and change its source when clicked on header

Comment: Change the `src` attribute of the icon image?

Comment: Can you post your ".header" style?

Comment: i dont have any specific style for the .header

Comment: `$(this).find("span").text("+");`

Comment: thanks epascarello - i tried this actually but it stays as a plus sign after its been clicked once...

Comment: changing the attribute of an image of icon may well be the way to go. chances are actually i will use a font awesome icon therefore could change the class...

Comment: Does this look like what you want?: http://jsfiddle.net/hhbrY/

Comment: exactly what i was after, great stuff and thanks for taking the time to put the fiddle together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of `span` inside `th` and use the [`::after` pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter).

Append `"open"` class to `th` from the beginning.

HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr class="header">
        <th colspan="7" class="open">HEADER</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Add CSS for displaying plus and minus sign "after" the `th.open` and `th.closed`:

```
th.open::after {
    font-family: Arial;
    content:'-';
    padding-left: 3px;
}

th.closed::after {
    font-family: Arial;
    content:'+';
    padding-left: 3px;    
}
```

In JavaScript swap `"open"` class with `"closed"` for `th` ([`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) receives space separated class names to be toggled) :

```
$('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').toggle();
    $(this).children("th").toggleClass('open closed');
});
```

Here is the [<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/J6WC7/)

Comment: this is excellent, many thanks for taking the time to code this up. Works a charm.